# create sectors with given azimuths of one point in QGIS and show tabs info. following each sector direction

Tags: qgis, azimuth

if there any way to create some sectors from one point with given azimuths,and show tab information on each sector following sector direction, or when i click the sector, all the information related to this sector can be shown.

the raw data:

ID  lon lat azimuths  sector_id

409970  113.243306  22.662132 9 10

409970  113.243306  22.662132 120 140

409970  113.243306  22.662132 256 260

the wanted style like this:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

1. Install plugin "Shapes Tool" on QGIS
2. Import site database in CSV
   [image: Import LTE sites database in CSV]

or

3. Import site database in Excel / Spreadsheet (easy to change attribute type Integer / Real / String / Date etc.)
   [image: Import LTE sites database in Excel or Spreadsheet]
4. Use Shapes Plugin to convert point to shapes using desired "Azimuth": In this scenario it requires 2 additionally defined columns to form a sector, it could be derived from actual "Azimuth" of the sector Per se, an offset of -/+ 20 degrees to the actual orientation would make sector BW 40 degrees from node, or as maybe required based on user requirements.

Starting angle field: 1st derived column with - 20 deg. angle: Pick corresponding column here

Ending angle field: 2nd derived column with +20 deg. angle: Pick corresponding column here

Radius field: Antenna size or Sector size should be derived in separate column as usual and input should be given to Radius under "Shape Tools" 
[image: create sectors with given azimuths of one point in QGIS]

5. In case of multi-technology site and to avoid overlay of sectors by random sizes follow arrange input data itself:
   Layer properties--> Style --> Control feature rendering order --> Expression --> Antenna size --> pick Descending under (Asc / Description) to have the sector overlay rendering order size large in bottom and size small on top for visibility onwards making map canvas in case CSV data or table data is not arranged earlier
   [image: Antenna Size / Technology wise Layer rendering order QGIS]

Sectors by label order in azimuth
[image: Telecom site sector labeling using QGIS]